# New York Public Library search query

Tags: ruby, json

I am attempting to access the NY Public Library digital collection through their api.

The ruby code I am using to make the call is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'pp'
require 'httparty'


    get '/' do
        url = "http://api.repo.nypl.org/api/v1/items/8568ccd0-c614-012f-1d74-58d385a7bc34.json"
        uri = URI.parse(url)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

        headers = { "Authorization" => "Token token=mytoken" }
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
        response = http.request(request)
        puts response
        @response = response.body
        erb :index
    end
```

So, a couple of questions:

1. This produces no result, nothing comes back with the puts response in the terminal, not even an error message. What am I doing wrong?
2. In any case, how do I attach a query at the end of the uri string? BY adding a ? followed by the query? So, for example, ?leonardodavinci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend you play around at the irb command prompt, e.g.

```
irb [enter]
```

Looks like not authorized perhaps? I eventually get `=> nil` myself with:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'sinatra'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> require 'pp'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> require 'httparty'
=> false
irb(main):006:0> url = "http://api.repo.nypl.org/api/v1/items/8568ccd0-c614-012f-1d74-58d385a7bc34.json"
=> "http://api.repo.nypl.org/api/v1/items/8568ccd0-c614-012f-1d74-58d385a7bc34.json"
irb(main):007:0>   uri = URI.parse(url)
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x9826744 URL:http://api.repo.nypl.org/api/v1/items/8568ccd0-c614-012f-1d74-58d385a7bc34.json>
irb(main):008:0>  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
=> #<Net::HTTP api.repo.nypl.org:80 open=false>
irb(main):009:0> headers = { "Authorization" => "Token token=mytoken" }
=> {"Authorization"=>"Token token=mytoken"}
irb(main):010:0> request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
=> #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
irb(main):011:0> response = http.request(request)
=> #<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Authorization Required readbody=true>
irb(main):012:0> puts response
#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized:0x9938a74>
=> nil
irb(main):013:0>
```

Comment: thanks, this is not the answer but I see where you are coming from. In fact (as you say) the issue is HTTP token not recognised which is strange as the token I am using is correct. I emailed NYPL api but no response.